# How can call a method in onCreateView Android

Tags: java, android, methods, fragment, retrofit

How can I call a  method in onCreateView in android `Fragment`?

onCreateView code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
    btnBusquedaUserList = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnBuscarUserList);
    rvUserList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvUserList);
    rvUserList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    txtCIbusqueda = (TextInputEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCIUserList);

    getActivity().setTitle("Lista Usuarios Check In");
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    idUsuario = args.getString("idLogueado");

    GetClient();

    btnBusquedaUserList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ciUser = txtCIbusqueda.getText().toString();
            Object lista[] = new Object[2];
            lista[0] = ciUser;
            lista[1] = idUsuario;
            parametroApi.setDatoG(lista);
            GetClient();

        }
    });

    return rootView;


};
```

My method `GetClient()`

```
public void GetClient() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://80.241.210.8:8080/Exma/Service/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ExmaApi service = retrofit.create(ExmaApi.class);
    Call<Respuesta<List<DataList>>>call=service.putClientList(parametroApi);

       call.enqueue(new Callback<Respuesta<List<DataList>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Respuesta<List<DataList>>> call, 
         Response<Respuesta<List<DataList>>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Respuesta<List<DataList>> respuesta = response.body();
                try {
                    if (respuesta.respuestaExitosa() == true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "TodoBien: " + respuesta.toString());
                        rvAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), respuesta);
                        rvUserList.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse" + "Ocurrio un Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Respuesta<List<DataList>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "TodoMal: " + t.getMessage().toString());

        }
    });


}
```

I have trouble when I want to call a method `GetClient()` in `onCreateView`, the method does not start, but in onClickListener from the button, the method start without problems, any way to call the method? in `onCreateView` from `Fragments`, I want to execute the method at the time that fragment start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Activities , Fragment have his own [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

> **onCreateView** : Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view. This is optional, and non-graphical fragments can
>   return null (which is the default implementation). This will be called
>   between onCreate(Bundle) and onActivityCreated(Bundle).

So you should move all initialization that doesn't concern graphical element in `onStart()`. For example :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
    btnBusquedaUserList = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnBuscarUserList);
    rvUserList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvUserList);
    rvUserList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    txtCIbusqueda = (TextInputEditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCIUserList);

    return rootView;
};

@Override
public void onStart() {

    getActivity().setTitle("Lista Usuarios Check In");
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    idUsuario = args.getString("idLogueado");
    GetClient();

    btnBusquedaUserList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ciUser = txtCIbusqueda.getText().toString();
            Object lista[] = new Object[2];
            lista[0] = ciUser;
            lista[1] = idUsuario;
            parametroApi.setDatoG(lista);
            GetClient();

        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thank you my friend, that works perfectly only i add super.onStart() en method onStart()